# Como obter diferentes arquivos outputs (fasta) com unix ou python

Tags: python, loop, unix

Eu tenho um arquivo fasta que tem varias sequencias de genes, como:

```
>gene1 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene
CGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG
>gene2 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene
AATTTCAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG
AATCCGGAGGACCGGTGTACTCAGCTCACCGGGGGCATTGCTCCCGTGGTGACCCTGATTTGTTGTTGGG
>gene3 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene
CGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG
>gene4
TTTTTTTTCCCTTTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

Eu tenho tambem varios arquivos chamados ids.txt com os genes ids separados em cada linha.

Por exemplo tenho o arquivo chamado id1.txt:

```
gene1
gene2
```

E muitos outros como por exemplo o id2.txt:

```
gene4
```

Eu quero rodar um script que gere arquivos fasta separados dependendo do meu id file e como input meu grande arquivo fasta com as sequencias (apenas um arquivo).
Por exemplo para o id2.txt, gerar um arquivo id2.fasta:

```
>gene4
TTTTTTTTCCCTTTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

E assim por diante...nao sei como fazer isso, tentei fazer com python, mas sou muito iniciante e so consegui fazer para um arquivo por vez, mas tenho 500 arquivos diferentes para os ids...

Alguma sugestao? Obrigada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Organização de Arquivos

Primeiro, vamos definir a organização dos nossos arquivos e o conteúdo em cada um.

```
 fasta/
   all.fasta
   id1.txt
   id2.txt
 fasta.py
```

**all.fasta** é o arquivo principal, que contém a informação por completo de todos os genes.

```
>gene1 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene
CGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG
>gene2 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene
AATTTCAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG
AATCCGGAGGACCGGTGTACTCAGCTCACCGGGGGCATTGCTCCCGTGGTGACCCTGATTTGTTGTTGGG
>gene3 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene
CGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG
>gene4
TTTTTTTTCCCTTTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

**id1.txt** contém uma lista de identificadores de genes.

```
gene1
gene2
```

**id2.txt** também possui uma lista de genes.

```
gene4
```

**fasta.py** é o arquivo Python que criaremos para executar o processo.

### Obtendo os dados

A primeira coisa a fazer no arquivo Python é ler o conteúdo de `fasta/all.fasta` e interpretar, obtendo os dados para cada gene separadamente.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

with open("fasta/all.fasta", 'r') as f:

    genes = {}

    fasta_content = f.read()
    genes_list = [_ for _ in fasta_content.split('>') if _]

    for gene in genes_list:
        gene_id = (gene.split('\n')[0]).split(' ')[0]
        genes[gene_id] = gene
```

Iniciamos abrindo o arquivo `all.fasta` como leitura, com a função [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open). Lemos todo seu conteúdo, com a função `read` e o armazenamos na variável `fasta_content`. Após, dividimos o conteúdo com base no caractere `>` para obter os dados referentes a cada gene separadamente. Posteriormente, iteramos sobre esta lista com a instrução `for`, onde primeiramente pegamos o identificador do gene, separando a primeira palavra da primeira linha (gene1, gene2, gene3, etc) e com isso populamos uma variável `genes`.

Até esta parte do código, teremos a variável `genes`, do tipo dicionário, no seguinte formato:

```
{
    "gene1": "gene1 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene\nCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG\n",
    "gene2": "gene2 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene\nAATTTCAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG\nAATCCGGAGGACCGGTGTACTCAGCTCACCGGGGGCATTGCTCCCGTGGTGACCCTGATTTGTTGTTGGG\n",
    "gene3": "gene3 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene\nCGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG\n",
    "gene4": "gene4\nTTTTTTTTCCCTTTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG"
}
```

### Obtendo as listas de genes

Agora iremos iterar sobre os arquivos textos nomeados com o padrão `idX.txt` dentro da pasta `fasta` a fim de obter a lista de genes para cada um e, posteriormente, criar o respectivo arquivo `idX.fasta`. Para isso, utilizamos a função [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html). Primeiro, importamos a biblioteca no início do arquivo.

```
import glob
```

Com isso, obtemos a lista de arquivos:

```
for id_file in glob.glob("fasta/id*.txt"):
    print(id_file)
```

A saída deste trecho deve ser algo do tipo:

```
fasta/id1.txt
fasta/id2.txt
```

### Gerando os arquivos fasta

Ao invés de imprimir o nome do arquivo, vamos abrí-lo para leitura.

```
for id_file in glob.glob("fasta/id*.txt"):
    with open(id_file, 'r') as idf:
        id_list = idf.readlines()
        print(id_list)
```

Neste momento, a saída deverá ser algo do gênero:

```
["gene1", "gene2"]
["gene4"]
```

Sendo as listas de genes definidas em cada arquivo. A partir dela, podemos criar o arquivo `idX.fasta` e escrever o conteúdo referente a cada gene da lista, como subsequente.

```
for id_file in glob.glob("fasta/id*.txt"):
    with open(id_file, 'r') as idf:
        id_list = idf.readlines()
        idX_name = "{}.fasta".format(id_file.split('.')[0])

        with open(idX_name, "w+") as idX_file:
            for id in id_list:
                idX_file.write(genes[id])
```

Ou seja, para cada arquivo do tipo `fasta/id*.txt`, abra como leitura, leia todas as linhas e armazene em `id_list`, retome o nome do arquivo com a extensão fasta (aqui a variável `idX_name` terá um valor `fasta/id*.fasta`). Após, abra o arquivo fasta em modo escrita e para cada id em `id_list`, escreva o respectivo conteúdo do gene identificado por `id`.

Desta forma, você já deve ter gerado todos os respectivos arquivos com o conteúdo correto.

### Arquivo fasta.py completo

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import glob

with open("fasta/all.fasta", 'r') as f:

    genes = {}

    fasta_content = f.read()
    genes_list = [_ for _ in fasta_content.split('>') if _]

    for gene in genes_list:
        gene_id = (gene.split('\n')[0]).split(' ')[0]
        genes[gene_id] = gene

    for id_file in glob.glob("fasta/id*.txt"):
        with open(id_file, 'r') as idf:
            id_list = idf.readlines()
            idX_name = "{}.fasta".format(id_file.split('.')[0])

            with open(idX_name, "w+") as idX_file:
                for id in id_list:
                    idX_file.write('>' + genes[id[:-1]])
```

### Resultado

Executando o código, são criados dois arquivos: `fasta/id1.fasta` e `fasta/id2.fasta`.

**fasta/id1.fasta**

```
>gene1 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene
CGTAACAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG
>gene2 C.irapeanum 5.8S rRNA gene
AATTTCAAGGTTTCCGTAGGTGAACCTGCGGAAGGATCATTGATGAGACCGTGGAATAAACGATCGAGTG
AATCCGGAGGACCGGTGTACTCAGCTCACCGGGGGCATTGCTCCCGTGGTGACCCTGATTTGTTGTTGGG
```

**fasta/id2.fasta**

```
>gene4
TTTTTTTTCCCTTTGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

Que acredito que era o desejado.

Comment: Muito obrigada Andreson pelas suas explicacoes e tempo. Tentei rodar mas deu erro: " File "./input_fasta.py", line 23, in <module>
    idX_file.write(genes[id])". Nao sei o que pode ser.

Comment: Havia dois erros, pois escrevi todo o código direto aqui e acabei nem testando na prática. Os dois se encontram na última linha: como o formato fasta inicia com o caractere `>`, precisa escrevê-lo no arquivo também. O outro erro era no índice `id`. Quando se é lido os índices com `readlines`, o caractere `\n` vem junto, então precisamos removê-lo, através de `[:-1]`. Editei a resposta com as soluções.

Comment: Sensacional. Muito obrigada pela ajuda! Funcionou perfeitamente. E com suas explicacoes da para entender cada parte e tentar aprender. Estou comecando a aprender python.

Comment: Se me permite a pergunta, qual a finalidade do código? Eu desconhecia este padrão até hoje.