# Ler arquivos fasta no python e ignorar a primeira linha

Tags: python, python-3.x, fasta

Preciso ler um arquivo [**fasta**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formato_FASTA), mas não sei como eliminar a primeira linha da sequência, exemplo:

```
>sequence A

ggtaagtcctctagtacaaacacccccaatattgtgatataattaaaattatattcatat tctgttgccagaaaaaacacttttaggctatattagagccatcttctttgaagcgttgtc
```

fazendo alguns testes percebi que se for acrescentado letras na primeira linha `>sequence aaaA` está sendo incluído na contagem.

Como faço para descartar a primeira linha da minha contagem de letras?

Comment: Você sabe ler uma linha inteira? Se sim, faça a primeira leitura e a jogue no lixo

Comment: Tem como explicar melhor? Qual é o conteúdo do arquivo exatamente? Qual é a linha que você deseja eliminar? Você já conseguiu ler o arquivo com o Python?

Comment: `ctagc` me lembra leitura de DNA. Eletroforese?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado editei a pergunta. Talvez fique mais fácil :)

Comment: O q vc quer dizer com 'primeira linha'? no que vc chamou de exemplo, tem quantas linhas? Dá para mostrar uma parte de um arquivo real?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento bem melhor mesmo! E realmente tinha a ver com bioinformática, pense num chute bem dado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado foi mesmo :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supondo que o arquivo tenha um formato semelhante a isto:

```
>SEQUENCE 1
MTEITAAMVKELRESTGAGMMDCKNALSETNGDFDKAVQLLREKGLGKAAKKADRLAAEG
LVSVKVSDDFTIAAMRPSYLSYEDLDMTFVENEYKALVAELEKENEERRRLKDPNKPEHK
IPQFASRKQLSDAILKEAEEKIKEELKAQGKPEKIWDNIIPGKMNSFIADNSQLDSKLTL
MGQFYVMDDKKTVEQVIAEKEKEFGGKIKIVEFICFEVGEGLEKKTEDFAAEVAAQL
>SEQUENCE 2
SATVSEINSETDFVAKNDQFIALTKDTTAHIQSNSLQSVEELHSSTINGVKFEEYLKSQI
ATIGENLVVRRFATLKAGANGVVNGYIHTNGRVGVVIAAACDSAEVASKSRDLLRQICMH
```

Presumo que o que você deseja remover sejam as linhas com este formato `>SEQUENCE xxxx` (ou semelhante), *de antemão* já lhe digo que não entendo nada deste formato, a não ser o que li nos Wikipédia a pouco, mas penso que o seu objetivo é simples, se for realmente apenas basta fazer a leitura linha por linha do arquivo FASTA.

```
arquivo = 'foo.dat'; # Seu arquivo "fasta"

f = open(arquivo, 'r') # Abre para leitura
lines = f.readlines() # Lê as linhas e separa em um vetor

relist = [] # cria um novo array para pegar somente as linhas de interesse

for line in lines:
    if line.find('>') != 0: # ignora as linhas que começam com >
        relist.append(line) 

print(relist) # Mostra o array no output
```

Agora se o que deseja é de fato remover a primeira linha, seja qual for, basta usar `.pop(0)`, assim:

```
arquivo = 'foo.dat';

f = open(arquivo, 'r')
lines = f.readlines() # Lê as linhas e separa em um vetor

firstLine = f.pop(0) #Remove a primeira linha

print(lines)
```

Para tornar a `array` em `string` ("texto") basta usar o `str.join(array)`, deve ficar assim para o primeiro exemplo:

```
''.join(relist)
```

E assim para o segundo:

```
''.join(lines)
```

Comment: Pelo que li do formato, cada sequência é identificado começando por `>`. E se for desejado o conteúdo da sequência?, ie, entre duas linhas começadas com `>`?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ae seria um vetor multi-dimensão, para cada linha com `>` encontrado é gerado um novo sub-vetor, o primeiro item do vetor seria o cabeçalho e as demais seriam as linhas e/ou dados, creio eu... Não é difícil de fazer e acho que ficaria massa :D, só vou aguardar o AP responder se é o que deseja, porque se não vou sair muito linhas xD

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181717/5878) eu faço um tratamento parecido com o que você comentou, se entendi bem.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sensacional sua resposta